# How to show corresponding infoWindow when click marker on Google map with javascript and JSTL

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, jstl, google-maps-markers

I am facing about the problem of displaying markers and infoWindows on a Google Map using JSTL in JSP (Taglib)
I have a listener setup in order to click a marker, the corresponding info window will shows (attached to the marker).

My problem is: I click any marker it only show 1 infowindow, when I another marker it can not show corresponding marker and infowindow..

my script:

```
<script>                                
function initMap() {
    var latLng = {lat:21.027763, lng:105.834160};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['mystyle', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
    },
    zoom: 13,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: 'mystyle'
    });
    map.mapTypes.set('mystyle', new google.maps.StyledMapType(myStyle, { name: 'My Style' }));                                  

    <c:forEach var="item" items="${itemList}">                                                   
        var content = '<div id="div-main-infoWindow">' +
                      '<div id="iw-container">' +
                      '<div class="iw-title">' +
                      '<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/photo/<c:out value="${item.THUMBNAIL_1}"/>" class="imgMarkerLabel">' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<h2><c:out value='${item.NAME}'/></h2>' +
                      '<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>';                                                   
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({                                           
            content: content, 
            maxWidth: 291
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
            $('#div-main-infoWindow').closest('.gm-style-iw').parent().addClass('custom-iw');
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: <c:out value="${item.LAT}"/>, lng: <c:out value="${item.MAPLONG}"/>},
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });                                                                             
    </c:forEach>                                        
}                                   
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);                                
</script>
```

I wish when I click any marker, that marker will show corresponding infowindow, and it will show property of list within infowindow
So, how can I access the info windows outside of this listener?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix JSTL with javascript like that. JSTL is rendered on the server side, which means the server will run that code before it runs the javascript. Javascript is rendered on the client side.

You can test this yourself by doing this:

```
<button onclick="doTest();">Test</button>

<script>

function doTest() {
//this should only run when we click on the button right?
<c:set var="testMe" value="Wrong." scope="session"  />

}     

</script>

<p>There should be no text below until we click the button right?</p>
<h1><c:out value="${testMe}"/></h1>
```

So you need to relook at your code keeping this in mind, that any jstl you have in your javascript will run first. This is why it will only show one infowindow.

What you need to do in order for this to work is pass your ${itemList} to a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" value="${itemList}" id="getItemList">
```

then in javascript you can access it and create the loop with javascript not jstl. Although you will need to convert the object to a string or json string first in order to use it in javascript.

You could do that with something like this in your java:

```
String someObjectAsJson = new Gson().toJson(itemList);
request.setAttribute("someObjectAsJson", someObjectAsJson);
```

then in js (instead of input method):

```
<script>var foo = ${someObjectAsJson};</script>
```

Note: that the EL in the javascript above works because the output is syntactically valid. If you don't make it a string first in your java you need to do it like this:

```
<script>var foo = '${foo}';</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I will try your suggestion and back when I finished